# sections of vector bundles

Tags: algebraic-curves, ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, rational-functions

Let $X$ a smooth projective connected curve over $\mathbb{C}$.
Let $E$ a vector bundle and $E'$ a subbundle of $E$.
Let $(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})$ $n$ closed points on the curve $X$ with $n>2g$ and $z$ an auxiliary closed point.
Can we find for all $m\geq 0$, a section $f\in H^{0}(X,E\otimes \mathcal{O}_{X}(D_{m}))$

with $D_{m}=[x_{1}]+\dots+[x_{n}]+m[z]$ such that at the points $x_{1},\dots,x_{n}$ the section $f$ factorizes through the subbundle $E'$?

Comment: Dear prochet, I think the question may need some extra conditions to admit a reasonable answer. As it stands, the answer seems to be either trivially yes, if the zero section is an acceptable answer, or trivially no, if the bundle E tensor O(D_m) doesn't have any nonzero global sections, e.g. if m < -deg E - n. 

Comment: edit to last comment: I meant to write, if E is a line bundle with m < -deg E -n.

Comment: Yes I shouldn't have formulate like this.
In fact, I only need the proposition for $V'\subset V$ two vector spaces such that $E$ (resp E') are the trivial vector bundles of fibres V and V'
